How does the phrase "a longe" meaning "from far away" make sense syntactically? Shouldn't it be "a longo"?

Erant autem ibi mulieres multæ a longe, quæ secutæ erant Jesum a Galilæa, ministrantes ei...
Matthæus 27:55

Most of the translations, as far as I can tell, translate "a longe" as "from far away". But how does that make sense syntactically? The preposition "a" takes the ablative case, and ablative from "longus" (long) is "longo". "Longe" is the vocative. So, how does that make sense?

Many (most?) prepositions can also be used as straight up adverbs. (I'm still enough of a beginner to be thrown off by ante sometimes which, in my experience, is the preposition most likely to be used as an adverb.) Woodcock (#4)speculates that prepositions in general originated as adverbs.
These origins are especially apparent when the preposition is used as a prefix (as Gaufridus points out in a comment). Exempli gratia: abest, abducere, abnormis, amens, etc.
So in this construction, I think of ab as an adverb modifying another adverb, longe. (NB, as Joonas points out, longe is not a noun here.)
Lewis and Short point out that using ab in this way is "for the most part peculiar to later Latinity". They go on to cite many examples, including ab intus (from within), a sursum (from above), ab invicem (from each other), etc. Click on the link for more examples.
Note that this usage is quite analogous to what we do in English. From is an English preposition which also serves as an adverb in from afar, from above, and from within, since afar, above, and within are not nouns.

It's perhaps worth adding explicitly that longe has a long E and is an adverb rather than a vocative.

Many prepositions began as adverbs. That’s why they so often occur as verbal prefixes. So when they occur as adverbs it is in fact the (pre)historical norm, which happens to have been made to seem anomalous by a later usage becoming more common. Another common source of pre/postpositions is case forms of nouns, also adverbial.

This answer seems very misleading to me, as ab is not used as an adverb here (nor anywhere else). If it were, then we would have to translate this as "far away," not "from far away," I believe. The remark in Lewis & Short that for some reason you only half quote actually starts: "The use of ab before adverbs is for the most part &c."
